# Google Data Studio Case Logic Using REGEXP_EXTRACT

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I am trying to create a dimension in Google Data Studio but can't.  I get no error, just a red line under the dialog box (which I guess is an error).

```
CASE WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, 'foo') THEN "Bar" ELSE "Other" END
```

I am not sure what is wrong with the format.  Has anyone been able to get this to work?

Comment: Can you take a screenshot?

Comment: [image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4dYcy-cQzmVQWJPUnBKUHZiTzQ)

Comment: Have you tried changing it to `CASE WHEN REGEXP_EXTRACT(landing_page, 'foo') != null THEN 'BAR' ELSE 'Other' END`. I am by no means an SQL expert but It I could see that the interpreter is looking for boolean to return rather than a string to verify the expression.

Comment: Orginally, I wasn't getting an error message, but now I am getting this message, "Invalid input expression - Unsupported filter".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax requires a `.*` for wildcards.  My original code was searching for exact match.

Here is the updated code for wildcards:

```
CASE WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Landing Page, '(foo.*)') THEN 'Bar' ELSE 'Other' END
```